# Deciding between Spark Photon and Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: firebase, raspberry-pi, wifi, iot, particles

I have an idea of an IOT product that only needs a relay that can be web-controlled.
I have already looked into Google's Firebase and Particle's products.
I'm having a hard time deciding between a Raspberry Pi Zero or a Particle Photon to control the relay.

Features of the Photon are easy prototyping and a library to easily implement wifi setup in an android or iOS app.
The thing I don't like about it is that it's really tied to the Particle Database service. It's almost impossible to use it with Firebase and their service is really expensive for the concept i'm looking into.

The Raspberry Pi Zero on the other hand is cheaper and more open. I would be able to use it with the Firebase service. The problem is that I couldn't find a good Wifi setup library on the internet. I want the Pi to create a Wifi access point for a smartphone to connect to and an app that then connects the pi to the local wifi network.

The perfect solution would be the board and wifi-setup/arduino-code SDK that Particle provides in combination with Firebase's (price)scaleable real time database.

Does anyone know any alternatives or do you have other suggestions?
Info on how to implement a wifi-setup app, like described, is always welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing with both systems and didn't really like the idea of being forced to used the Particle Publish system.

Thankfully you don't have to as they have a standard HTTP library ready (and very easy) to include in your project so you can GET and POST to any url you wish. Very handy if you just want to push to APIs etc.

I suppose it just comes down to power consumption and size of the chip if you can now do everything with both systems.

Oh, have you seen the Particle Pi system that came out a few months ago? This question I'm answering is probably a little old now as Pi Zero W is out with WiFi and Bluetooth included. Personally, I'm Pi Zero as you can do much more with it if power consumption isn't a problem (Pi Zero is probably double power consumption in everyday use).